# iniciar uma função depois de X minutos em uma página com php

Tags: php

Por exemplo :

Tenho uma página que executa uma função depois de 7 minutos nela.

Essa função vai aumentar "+1" em um campo do meu banco de dados.

Comment: não ficou claro, vc já tem  o codigo do que deseja fazer ? você  poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta ? aparentemente procura pela função sleep()

Comment: Tem muitas respostas no site sobre isto, cada uma usando um _approach_ diferente. Seria o caso de você [edit] a postagem sendo mais específico em relação ao ambiente que isto vai ser executado. Dependendo do caso, o caminho pode ser o cron do linux ou agendador de tarefas do windows. Dependendo do caso, pode ser o caso de um JS na sua página, dependendo do caso pode ser outra solução que não passe perto dessas mencionadas. Raramente uma solução PHP pura vai ser adequada (salvo se tratar de um executável local fazendo uma tarefa extensa, o que nao se aplica a "uma página" como mencionado)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Isso se chama **processamento assíncrono**. Existem diversas formas de fazer isso, a primeira:

```
<?php

// Seu codigo aqui...

// Aqui chama o script que será executado em 7 minutos
exec("php executarApos7Min.php");

// ...
```

Código do executarApos7Min.php

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

//Pausa
sleep(420);

// sua query que soma +1
```

Outra forma:

```
$socketCon = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if($socketCon) {   
   $socketDados = "GET www.meuserver.com.br/executarApos7Min.php HTTP 1.1\r\nHost: $host\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";      
   fwrite($socketCon, $socketDados); 
   fclose($socketConexao);
}
```

Comment: Olá, João. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta provavelmente recebeu votos negativos porque faltou um pouco de contexto sobre as abordagens mencionadas nela e também porque a pergunta não está clara, logo fica bem difícil para quem ler esta pergunta determinar se os códigos realmente resolvem algum problema e em quais casos eles são úteis e podem ser aplicados. Minha sugestão para evitar receber negativos no futuro é se certificar primeiro que a pergunta é clara e de que você está respondendo-a objetivamente, se possível dando algum contexto sobre sua solução.

Comment: Os usuários do site em geral votam conforma a qualidade da pergunta e resposta. Se tiver dúvidas, pode começar a ler sobre [como responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Abraço!